# How to get all AccountSubTypeEnums for a given AccountTypeEnum?

Tags: java, quickbooks-online

I am integrating Quickbooks Java API in my project. I am trying to get the AccountSubTypeEnums for a given AccountType. Is there an API to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this.

However, Intuit does publish `.XSD`s for the schema, which contain all of the constants used, and are available here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/learn/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/minor-versions

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. I will check out the XSD.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest XSD file (v65). I can't see one-to-many relationships between AccountTypeEnum -> AccountSubTypeEnum or AccountClassificationEnum -> AccountTypeEnum. I'm looking at \sb-domain-services-cdm-types-v3-1.0.0-rel-252\CDM\cdm-types-v3\xsd\finance.xsd - wrong file?